# How to reference a deployment contributor from a sqlproj file?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I've been researching the use of deployment contributors within a SQL Server project (SSDT).  The documentation indicates that deployment contributors must be placed in a folder within the Visual Studio installation location (for example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\Extensions).

This structure will require every developer on the project must install the deployment contributors.  I would like to instead include the deployment contributors within my solution so they can be checked in to source control.  I'm looking for a way to configure my .sqlproj project so that it can reference deployment contributors from a non-default folder.

I've browsed through the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql and Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Common assemblies, and noticed that there are properties named AdditionalDeploymentContributorPaths (in the  CommandLineResources class) and DeploymentContributorPaths (on the AmbientSettings class).  These appear to provide a way to specify other folders, but I haven't found a way to set this value from within my sqlproj file.  Is there an msbuild property that provides this function?

Are there any other options within a sqlproj file that will allow other folders to be searched for deployment contributors?